# PHP values not populating in sql database?

Tags: php, html, sql, database, insert

I've got a simple form to take in user data and insert it into an sql database.  When the user hits submit it does create a new entry line (so I know it's connecting to the database) but none of the values are posting as they should. I was following the tutorials on w3schools but I'm not sure where my Values are getting lost. Could some one point me in the right direction?

Form:

```
<?php
$Fname = $_POST["Fname"];
$Lname = $_POST["Lname"];
$Sid = $_POST["Sid"];
$Email = $_POST["Email"];
$Dtype = $_POST["Dtype"];
$Mac = $_POST["Mac"];
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Register School Device</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="SMA_Send.php">
First Name:<input type="text" size="12" maxlength="20" name="Fname"><br />
Last Name:<input type="text" size="12" maxlength="36" name="Lname"><br />
Student ID:<input type="text" size="12" maxlength="12" name="Sid"><br />
Email:<input type="text" size="12" maxlength="36" name="Email"><br />
Device Type:<br />
<select name="Dtype">
<option value="iPad">iPad</option>
<option value="iPhone">iPhone</option>
<option value="AndroidTablet">Android Tablet</option>
<option value="AndroidPhone">Android Phone</option></select><br />
Mac Address:<input type="text" size="12" maxlength="36" name="Mac"><br />
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Send:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO StudentDeviceReg (Fname, Lname, Sid, Email, Dtype, Mac, Date)
VALUES ('$Fname','$Lname','$Sid','$Email','$Dtype','$Mac',NOW())";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: You need to put the values in the variables on the page which inserts it in to the database, not on the page with the form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These belong in your PHP/SQL **SMA_Send.php** file and not in your form.

```
$Fname = $_POST["Fname"];
$Lname = $_POST["Lname"];
$Sid = $_POST["Sid"];
$Email = $_POST["Email"];
$Dtype = $_POST["Dtype"];
$Mac = $_POST["Mac"];
```

Having used [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php), would have signaled Undefined variables.

I also need to note that your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Welp I feel silly, that worked thanks.  Looking into prepared statements now, appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

i don't see you using `$_POST` any where:

use `$_POST["Fname"]` and others also like this.

or you can do this:

```
$Fname = $_POST["Fname"];// for the rest also.
```